# Angular currency: Expected '€ 3,14' to equal '€ 3,14'. Why are these unequal?

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I wrote unit tests for an angular filter that makes use of angular's currency filter, and somehow all unit tests are failing, despite the fact that the actual strings it's comparing are identical.

What could be causing this?

Another filter that does something very similar but without using angular's currency filter works fine. Does the currency filter put some weird symbols in the string that can't be detected by the naked eye? How do I figure this out?

Comment: show your code please

Comment: We have absolutely no idea what you are comparing code wise, or even if the data exists when you are comparing. Where's your code?

Comment: I'm comparing the output of, ultimately, the currency filter, to a string that looks identical to it. The data is clearly there (as shown in the title). The issue is really nothing more than: "does the currency filter put anything funny in its output?" Fortunately @JB Nizet got it in one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AngularJS uses a non-breaking space between the amount and the currency (in your locale at least). Replace your code with

```
expect(formattedValue).toBe('€\u00a03,14');
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I needed to know.

Comment: This solution is still working in angular 4 when using the CurrencyPipe